# Self referencing function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering how to define the type for the `defaultEncoder` parameter. It has the same parameters as the function itself.

```js
const paramsSerializer = (params: Params) => {
  const encoder = (
    str: string,
    defaultEncoder: any,
    charset: string,
    type: string
  ) => {
    const encodedStr = defaultEncoder(str, defaultEncoder, charset, type);
    return transformEncodedStr(encodedStr)
  };

  return transformParams(params, { encoder });
}
```

If I define the `defaultEncoder` every time it would be an infinite sequence of types.

```js
defaultEncoder: (
  str: string,
  encoder: (
    str: string,
    encoder: // And so on...
    charset: string,
    type: "key" | "value"
  ) => any,
  charset: string,
  type: "key" | "value"
) => any,
```

Comment: It's easier if you extract the type:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN5VQe2QgC4oAiVYAVwDMayoBfAbgChXRIoBRAOwGN8AEwgJMUABSsoeYAlKUEAS14BzADTSoImnCoAbYH0Ej5PAcNGaZ-ABaJUEYArkqNWziVnK1rAJSYAHzebmysNFQCwEr4vFBycLyoNPgIyPBIaBJgiCiopBl56lD4YNGx+ThQEBampMaWYox+Lj6qOFoITlQIcWS2SmSsjOwRUTFxCUkpaQ0iQgDKchI1JhBCrW4tIWodMl3UveQA7nDAQyOsgknAUDmZqAuiSnD6SgBeouLZuWgFv6gAhhgtgtNdKNVaqJ6lCxFgJIpijo9IY5lYoHYHE5ip4gSCtDYKrdVpZFnJxMiDEZYQi5EiILoqWiEMVMQhHMAceAIH42DJ9t0jlNkqlkGiyQgVlCJX4tCx2ALDpMkNNRYUsvcilUSaYmLzhqwgA

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks a  lot. Didn't know that I can use the same type in the own type definition. Maybe you can post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonrsharpe said in his comment you should extract the type to a type alias to recursively use it:

```ts
type Encoder = (
  str: string,
  defaultEncoder: Encoder,
  charset: string,
  type: string
) => string;
```

Then you can use it in the encoder function:

```ts
const paramsSerializer = (params: Params) => {
  const encoder = (
    str: string,
    defaultEncoder: Encoder, // here
    charset: string,
    type: string
  ) => {
    const encodedStr = defaultEncoder(str, defaultEncoder, charset, type);
    return transformEncodedStr(encodedStr)
  };

  return transformParams(params, { encoder });
}
```

To make it simpler you can use the `Encoder` type in the function definition itself:

```ts
const paramsSerializer = (params: Params) => {
  const encoder: Encoder = (str, defaultEncoder, charset, type) => {
    const encodedStr = defaultEncoder(str, defaultEncoder, charset, type);
    return transformEncodedStr(encodedStr)
  };

  return transformParams(params, { encoder });
}
```

Comment: If you do `const encoder: Encoder = ...` you don't need to reiterate all of the types of the parameters.

Comment: Yeah, that's also an option.

Comment: It's not just "an option"; it actually lets the compiler check the function _is_ an `Encoder`, especially helpful as it includes the return type that's otherwise missed out.